# Is there anyway to modify stat information like mtime or ctime manually in Python or any language at all?

Tags: python, posix, stat

I am trying the following code:

```
os.stat(path_name)[stat.ST_CTIME] = ctime
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
exceptions.TypeError: 'posix.stat_result' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there anyway to modify ctime?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the system time, create a new hard link to the file and rename it. Change the system time back.

Comment: You'd be modifying the copy of the values you got from the OS, not what the OS actually uses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`os.utime(filename, timetuple)` can be used to set the atime and mtime  of a file. As far as I know there is no way to modify the ctime from userland without resorting to hacks such as playing with the clock or direct edition of the filesystem (which I really do not recommend), and this is true for any programming language (Python, Perl, C, C++...) : it's internal OS stuff, and you don't want to touch it.

See for example in the documentation of the `touch` command (http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/fileutils/fileutils_54.html):

> Although touch provides options for
>   changing two of the times -- the times
>   of last access and modification -- of
>   a file, there is actually a third one
>   as well: the inode change time. This
>   is often referred to as a file's
>   ctime. The inode change time
>   represents the time when the file's
>   meta-information last changed. One
>   common example of this is when the
>   permissions of a file change. Changing
>   the permissions doesn't access the
>   file, so the atime doesn't change, nor
>   does it modify the file, so the mtime
>   doesn't change. Yet, something about
>   the file itself has changed, and this
>   must be noted somewhere. This is the
>   job of the ctime field. This is
>   necessary, so that, for example, a
>   backup program can make a fresh copy
>   of the file, including the new
>   permissions value. Another operation
>   that modifies a file's ctime without
>   affecting the others is renaming. In
>   any case, **it is not possible, in
>   normal operations, for a user to
>   change the ctime field to a
>   user-specified value.**

Answer (score 3):

GNU stroke implements the change-system-time trick to change ctime of a file. If that's what you want, GNU stroke does it for you: http://stroke.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to set change time, it gets updated whenever inode information changes, like ownership, link count, mode, etc..

Try setting the mode to the already set mode:

```
os.chmod(path_name, os.stat(path_name)[stat.ST_MODE])
```

Comment: ctime is creation time, not "change time". You can set the mtime (and atime) arbitrarily, not the ctime.

Comment: @Wooble: from man fstat "time_t st_ctime; /* time of last status change */"

Comment: @Wooble: ctime: time of last status change [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(Unix)]

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this lately, this is how I ended up doing it:

```
def _update_ctime(filename, cdatetime): 
    args = [ 
        'sudo', 
        'touch', 
        '-d', str(cdatetime)[:19], 
        filename, 
    ] 
    proc = subprocess.run(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
    if proc.returncode != 0: print('=> Error changing time on file {}'.format(cdatetime))
```

Not error proof (depending on locales, etc, but can be improved...