# How to make pywin32 work with pyinstaller to make an executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a code where I had to change creation time of a file to creation time of another file (copying creation time from one file to another). I could find some answers about changing creation time on the following links and they work very well as well.

[How do I change the file creation date of a Windows file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996405/how-do-i-change-the-file-creation-date-of-a-windows-file)

[Modify file create / access / write timestamp with python under windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21156145/modify-file-create-access-write-timestamp-with-python-under-windows)

But when I try to put the code mentioned in an executable using pyinstaller it shows the following error:

*AttributeError: 'pywintypes.datetime' object has no attribute 'astimezone'*

**How can I get over this error?**

Below is the code which can be used to reproduce the situatuion

```py
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con, ntsecuritycon
import os

def changeFileCTime(fname, createdNewtime):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(int(createdNewtime))
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(fname, ntsecuritycon.FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, 0, None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING, 0, None)
    win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, None, None)
    winfile.close()

def main():
    filename = input("File to copy creation time from: ")
    ctime = os.path.getctime(filename)

    filename = input("File to set ctime to: ")
    changeFileCTime(filename, ctime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Versions of programs:

- Python - 3.8.2
- Pyinstaller - 4.1

pyinstaller code:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --console test.py
```

where test.py is the filename with the above code.

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue today with both: pyinstaller and nuitka exe builder. Have you found any solution to that? If so - would you mind posting here as an answer?